# Porting code from Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I have this small piece of code that I'm shifting from Matlab to C++.

However there is a huge change in values and Run Time errors when I'm trying to display values from my resulting array.

> XR2 and YR2 are arrays with 7202 elements. They change to 3201 elements after the code.

Matlab Code:

```
XR = so(1,:);
YR = so(2,:);
XR2 = XR;
YR2 = YR;
i = 1;
j = 1;

while(i<=numel(YR2))
    if(i>1)
        if(XR2(i)>0 && XR2(i-1)<0)
            j = i;
        end
    end
    if(YR2(i)<0.0)
        YR2(i) = [];
        XR2(i) = [];
        i = i - 1;
    end
    i = i +1;
end
```

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
void main()
{

vector<double> XR2(7202);
vector<double> YR2(7202);
ifstream myReadFile1, myReadFile2;
int h=0;
myReadFile1.open("XR.txt");
myReadFile2.open("YR.txt");
while (!myReadFile1.eof())
{
    myReadFile1 >> XR2[h];
    ++h;
}
myReadFile1.close();
h=0;
while (!myReadFile2.eof())
{
    myReadFile2 >> YR2[h];
    ++h;
}
myReadFile2.close();

int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (i < XR2.size())
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        if ((XR2[i]>0) && (XR2[i-1]<0))
        {
            j = i;
        }
    }
    if (YR2[i]<0.0)
    {
        YR2.erase(YR2.begin() + i);
        XR2.erase(XR2.begin() + i);
        --i; 
    }
    ++i;
}
}
```

When I try to display the values from YR2 in C++, I get run time errors and the values displayed before the error are also different from expected results.

Link to the input data (XR and YR) and the expected output data(XR2 and YR2). The data is in text files.

> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uy4cxi67rm9dspr/AAApawshcLxa1h0LfBC_rnLla?dl=0

Comment: Are you sure thatt the matlab code is actually relevant to debug your c++ code? I'd rather invest the time to provide a [MCVE] for your c++ code (which you didn't). This is much more important to help you, instead of seeing the running matlab code.

Comment: i can maybe attach the data file (It's a simple 1 dimensional array) before and after the loop in matlab. I'm adding the same values to XR2 and YR2 before the loop in C++.

Comment: Did you read the link what's actually required to make a MCVE? 1st of all post compilable code, input and expected output is helpful as well.

Comment: I have made a compilable program and added the input files and output files in the link.

Comment: can you set the numbers to some "large" negative number that will be ignored during data processing instead of trying to remove the data points from the vectors?

Comment: Actually I can't. I need the trimmed down vector. The vector basically gets half its elements eliminated this way and I want that resulant half data to do further processing.

Comment: In the code posted you didn't reserve any space for the `std::vector`s, you should use [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [`resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the vectors before accessing with `[]`.

Comment: @Bob__ I have changed it. My bad.

Comment: @RahulKaruppiah Your data set is very big (7202 values). Try working with a smaller data set (e.g. 10 elements), and see if you can reproduce the error. If you can, [edit] your post and include the data there. If you cannot, you should mention that in your post (e.g. when removing even 1 value, the error cannot be reproduced). This is very important (MCVE = **minimal** complete verifiable example).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the posted code, it seems to me that the OP could simply create the final vectors on the fly, adding only the wanted values.

Assuming that the posted logic is all what OP needs, a complete program which reads the original files and writes the trimmed outputs can be this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{

    std::vector<double> XR2,
                        YR2;

    std::ifstream ifile_xr("XR.txt"),
                  ifile_yr("YR.txt");
    if ( !ifile_xr || !ifile_yr ) {
        std::cout << "Error: unable to open input files.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    double x, y;
    while ( ifile_xr >> x  &&  ifile_yr >> y )
    {
        if ( y >= 0.0 )
        {
            XR2.push_back(x);
            YR2.push_back(y);
        }
    }

    std::ofstream ofile_xr("XR2.txt"),
                  ofile_yr("YR2.txt");
    if ( !ofile_xr || !ofile_yr ) {
        std::cout << "Error: unable to open output files.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < XR2.size(); ++i ) {
        ofile_xr << std::setprecision(15) << XR2[i] << '\n';
        ofile_yr << std::setprecision(15) << YR2[i] << '\n';
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```